# Element does not have a match in class

Tags: simple-framework

I am working with Simple XML framework, and just renamed some XML layouts, which now don't seem to work any more.

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <orderListReply id="R000000000006">
    <order orderid="12" type="outbound" state="available">
       <todo>2</todo>
       <done>0</done>
       <lines>1</lines>
       <erporderid>0</erporderid>
    </order>
  </orderListReply>
```

And this is my code class definition:

```
@Root(name="orderListReply")
public class OrderListReplyTelegram extends Telegram {

    @ElementList(name="order", inline=true, required=false)
    private List<OrderListItem> orders;
    ...
```

This is the error I get:

> org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'order' does not have a match in class nl.minerall.sapphire.pocket.telegrams.OrderListReplyTelegram at line 1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, debugging Simple XML Framework isn't easy, but some trial and error helped me.

My `OrderListItem` class had this header:

```
@Element(name="order")
public class OrderListItem {
```

when changed to this:

```
@Root(name="order")
public class OrderListItem {
```

it worked. Strange thing is, in other code, the `@Element` annotation seemed to work (this code comes from another, working, tree).

Comment: I note that the annotation @Root is mandatory. Also you can use @Root(strict = false)