# Retrofit 2 Xml Parse "Parameter 'DASH' does not have a match in class"

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, model, xml-parsing

I am using **retrofit** with **SimpleXmlConverterFactory**. I tried every combination I know but I keep getting this error also I checked several questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741617/parameter-does-not-have-a-match-simplexml/48209460) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29493840/element-does-not-have-a-match-in-class). But I couldn't figure it out.

```
Parameter 'DASH' does not have a match in class com.example.exoplayer.api.model.XmlGroupList
```

Final version of my model is like this:

```
@Root(name = "DASH", strict = false)
data class DASH(
    @Attribute(required = true)
    val Name: String?,
    @Attribute(required = true)
    val DRM: String?,
    @Attribute(required = true)
    val StreamLink: String?)


data class XmlGroupList(
    @Element(name = "DASH", required = false)
    val DASH: DASH,
    @ElementList(name = "Thumbnail", inline = true)
    val Thumbnail: List<Thumbnail>?
)

@Root(name = "Thumbnail", strict = false)
data class Thumbnail(
    @Attribute(required = true)
    val Name: String?,
    @Attribute(required = true)
    val DRM: String?,
    @Attribute(required = true)
    val StreamLink: String?
)
```

And the Xml is:

```
<GroupList>
<DASH Name="LivePreset_test Output" StreamLink="www.xxxx.xxxx.mpd" DRM="0"/>
<Thumbnail Name="Thumbnail Output" StreamLink="www.xxxx.xxxx.vtt" DRM="0"/>
<Thumbnail Name="Poster Output" StreamLink="www.xxxx.xxxx.vtt" DRM="0"/>
</GroupList>
```